# Git Unable to push code from Initial Commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have some code from a C# project which I trying to commit with Git into Bitbucket.

The C# code is in one folder and inside this folder are two other folders or projects, but when I try to commit these projects at the step when you call git add --all it shows a warning that I have two repositories in one, and only one of the projects is committed to Bitbucket.

There is only one remote repository for all of the c# code, and want to keep things together. The folder structure is as follows:

```
-Parent Folder
    -Project One Folder
    -Project Two Folder (this contains the solution file)
```

As I said it is only the first folder Project One that is saved to Bitbucket. I have tried to upload each Project folder separately, but it throws an error saying there is not a repository for these folders.

So, my question is there a way with Git where I can upload from the Parent Folder both folders into one repository?

Comment: How did you initialize the repository? Did you just use `git clone`? There seem to be two local git repositories, i.e. two `.git` folders, maybe one in the parent folder and one in another folder? What exactly is the warning message `git add --all` is showing?

Comment: I did a git clone before doing anything, and then cd into the parent folder and did a git init, git add --all, git commit -m "Start", git remote set-url origin <url>, git push -u origin master. There was .git in the parent folder, nothing in the project one folder, and there was one in the second which I removed

Comment: Sorry, I managed to fix it now

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you did `git clone`, which creates a git repository, and then did `git init` on top of that, which initializes *another* repository. That explains the two-repository state you're in.

You should find out where the two `.git` folders are and delete the one that was *not* created by the clone. You can find out by taking a look inside the `.git/config` file: one of them should contain something like

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@your_bitbucket_url
    ...
```

That is the one to keep! Delete the `.git` folder *NOT* containing an entry for the remote you cloned. That should fix your repository and allow you to commit and push.